# What is this port labeled "ONT" and what does it do?

Tags: router, modem

This image is from the back of an AT&T uverse 3801hgv modem. What the purpose is of this port.

[image]:

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like it is for connecting to a Optical Network Terminal (ONT). What is a ONT then?

From [dslreports](http://www.dslreports.com/faq/12565):

> An ONT is a media converter that is installed by Verizon either
>   outside or inside your premises, during FiOS installation. The ONT
>   converts fiber-optic light signals to copper/electric signals.
>
> Each ONT is capable of delivering:
>
> - Multiple POTS (plain old telephone service) lines
> - Internet data
> - Video

The wikipedia article has some more information [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_interface_device#Optical_network_terminals)

> An ONT (optical network terminal) is used to terminate the fiber optic
>   line, demultiplex the signal into its component parts (voice
>   telephone, television, and Internet), and provide power to customer
>   telephones